# Numerical Approximations to the Cumulative Distribution Function of the Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have been trying to write the code for the Cumulative Distribution function (CDF) of the normal distribution in C++. Since the cdf does not have a closed form solution of the integral, I was wondering what approximations are generally used for the implementation in any programming language. Can anyone please explain how the approximating function is equal to the integral/cdf in some detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558256/numerical-method-for-approximating-the-standard-normal-distribution-cdf-with-mea/1558540#1558540)

Answer (score 1):

[Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/frameindex.htm) give a number of approximations.  One with only five constants is accurate to $1.5 \cdot 10^{-7}$  [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) page 221 has an expansion that quotes slightly better errors. Neither explains where they come from, but you could look at the references.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the derivation for the approximation is not given anywhere then but will try to see the references.